# Converting uint8 array to image

Tags: python, ruby, image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to convert a `uint8 array` of a 48x48 image to its corresponding 48x48 image file (jpg/jpeg/gif). I tried converting the array contents to first binary and then wrote ('wb' mode) it to a file, but that did not work out.

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: You could convert numpy array to PIL.image and then use "save" method to encode it into jpg

Comment: @Yaroslav Yup there is a way to do this using the PIL library https://www.kaggle.com/c/challenges-in-representation-learning-facial-expression-recognition-challenge/forums/t/4393/data-set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are producing the image in TensorFlow (as I'm inferring from your tag), you can use the [`tf.image.encode_jpeg()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/image.html#encode_jpeg) or [`tf.image.encode_png()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/image.html#encode_png) ops to encode a `uint8` tensor as an image:

```
uint8_data = ...
image_data = tf.image.encode_png(uint8_data)
```

The result of either op is a `tf.string` tensor that you can evaluate and write out to a file.

Comment: Thanks @mrry! Btw I found a way to do this using the PIL python library https://www.kaggle.com/c/challenges-in-representation-learning-facial-expression-recognition-challenge/forums/t/4393/data-set

Answer (score 1):

I was able to the same very easily using Octave.
Here i have tried to generate a random matrix of 48x48 and then i saved the image as jpg format.

```
img = rand(48,48);
imwrite(img, "test.jpg")
```

[image: Image of 48x48]

You can save any type of image with this approach.

If you can give some more details about what you want to achieve. Do u need to do it just once or u need it as part of program.

Hope that helped.